# Ошибка IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

При переходе из фрагмента в другую активность возникает следующая ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.apps.gragas.storydirector, PID: 9919
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 3
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:617)
        at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:565)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:527)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1502)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Научите, пожалуйста, как разобраться, с чем именно она связана, и в каком месте кода возникает? Опытным путем выяснил, что "сломалось" именно в коде второй активности.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 3` означает, что индекс, который вы подсовываете массиву равен 6, а текущий размер этого массива (`ArrayList`) равен 3 вот в этом процессе `Process: com.apps.gragas.storydirector, PID: 9919`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Проблема во втором спиннере в активности.